# Searching for a specific Unicode character returns all posts

Tags: bug, search, unicode

I'm searching for answers where the ⎋ character appears.

https://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20%E2%8E%8B

However, it returns 342,562 posts – all the answers you'd get when you just search for `is:answer`. I'd expect only few of those to contain that character.

Comment: I can't even see the character.

Comment: @3ventic probably a banana

Comment: @ShadowWizard [This character apparently](http://superuser.com/a/325482/33047). Doesn't display correctly in Safari ios7 either. Normally it displays the bananas etc. fine!

Comment: Hu, makes any text go into Courier New on Chrome: http://imgur.com/oz2YNPd, the same when I select, right click: the Search with Google is in CN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use double quotes (`"`) around the character: [Super User search example](https://superuser.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%22%E2%8E%8B%22)

That only returns 5 results, instead of 342 563.

Comment: Alos, removing the `is:answer` part returns [two additional results](http://superuser.com/search?q=%E2%8E%8B) (total of 7)

Comment: @AlexR: well he was looking for _answers_, but yes that's true.

Comment: Yeah, but filtering out the two questions shouldn't be toom much of a hassle, so this might be "faster" to achieve.

Comment: I get no matches for that.